# Laravel update multiple of the same belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have an `Orders` table and a `Products` table, my relationship between these is setup as a `belongsToMany` relationship, which works fine.

However, an Order can have the same Product multiple times (in case they want to order more and the admin can offer a discount).

For example:

```
Order 1 has

Product 1 x 5 (£1 each = £5 total)
Product 1 x 2 (£0.75 each = £1.50 total)
```

How can I update a single row? I have tried the following, but this updates all of the rows as it only accepts the product ID:

```
$order->products()->updateExistingPivot($productID, $values);
```

I have also tried the following, but the `wherePivot` doesn't seem to have much effect when calling the `update` method as all of the rows for this product are updated

```
$pivotProduct = $order->products()->wherePivot('id', $pivotId)->first();
$pivotProduct->pivot->price = '0.75';
$pivotProduct->pivot->update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by doing the following:

```
 $pivotProduct = $order->products()->wherePivot('id', $pivotId)->first();
 $pivotProduct->pivot->where('id', $pivotId)->update($values);
```

This second line ensures that only the row with the same pivotId is updated.